# Inserting data into mysql db from csv file using sidekiq and smarter_csv

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sidekiq

Im using Sidekiq (https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq) for background processing in my rails application. I need to insert 75,000 records   into a mysql db from a csv file. Im using smarter_csv (https://github.com/tilo/smarter_csv) in conjunction with sidekiq to insert the data in chunks into the db. I have the following questions

1. Is the maximum number of workers for sidekiq 25 ?
2. What is the maximum possible pool size for a mysql db and what should be the optimum value of pool size i should use for minimum possible transfer time ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. `sidekiq -c 50` creates 50 processors (default is 25)
2. MySql accepts 100 connections by default. If you change the `pool` size in `database.yml`, make sure you enter a value less or equal then the number of connections MySql can handle. I don't know what the optimal value is, I think it depends on the amount of RAM available.